# Python 3: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python-3.x, module

I am trying to create a small lib package. I use Python 3.6.7 on Windows and Linux.
This is my directory structure:

```
my_lib\
     setup.py
     README.md
     my_lib\
        libname.py
        __init__.py
     tests\
        test.py
```

For wheel creation I use: `python setup.py bdist_wheel`

From another machine I do: `(venv) pip install my_lib.whl`

But when I try to import the module it says: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_lib.libname'**

When I do 'pip list' there is a package '**my-lib**'

When I run python help('modules') there is a module **my_lib**

Is there any way to resolve this error without fixing sys.path?

Answer (score 0):

Actually global `pip uninstall pytest` and then `(venv)pip install pytest` helped locally. Still need a solution for remotes